Intermittent BT.656 Video Data Corruption Using TVP5150, FPGA, and Xillybus PCIe Interface
I’m working on a video pipeline where a PAL video signal is converted to BT.656 by a TVP5150 decoder. The BT.656 stream is then sent to an FPGA, which forwards the data to a processor over a Xillybus PCIe single lane connection.
The issue I’m facing is that every 8th byte in the received byte stream becomes 0, which disrupts the video signal, including synchronization preambles. For example:
Expected stream (working board):
`128, 16, 128, 16, 128, 16, ...`

Corrupted stream (non-working board):
`128, 16, 128, 16, 128, 0, 128, 16, ...`

Observations:

The corruption is consistent and periodic, affecting every 8th byte.

The problem does not occur on all boards so i am ruling out the firmware.


Steps Taken:

Verified the TVP5150 configuration (PAL input and BT.656 output are correct).
Logged raw data read from Xillybus and observed the inconsistent 0 values which sometimes corrupt the SAV or EAV

Questions:

What could cause periodic corruption of every 8th byte in a video byte stream?

How can I debug synchronization issues between the FPGA and the processor?

Could this be a clock domain crossing issue, and how do I verify it?

Are there specific configurations or practices I should follow to avoid data corruption with Xillybus?



"The problem does not occur on all boards so i am ruling out the firmware" - I wouldn't be so quick to do that. Differences between boards suggests a timing or metastability issue that shows up on some boards more than others due to e.g. process variation.

As it stands the question is too broad - until you can pinpoint the problem there is literally no way of us pointing you to the source because we can't see any of your setup and code. Beyond the usual - simulate the firmware, check through the design to ensure you are following best practices, make sure any clock domain crossings use proper synchronization, etc.
